# Custom notification layout gives unnecessary margin

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I am creating a custom notification layout for my application.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_icon)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setCustomContentView(notificationLayoutCollapsed)
            .setOngoing(playing)
            .setCustomBigContentView(notificationLayoutExpanded)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

[image]

 
 
My notification layout does not have internal padding or margins yet there it shows margins for the notification (Thick white border around blue notification).

Please suggest a solution to this issue.

----ANSWER-----

Culprit is this following line

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
```

DecoratedCustomViewStyle gives the notification a border

Comment: Please check edit, anwered the question