# Android notification: always expanded + rectangular

Tags: android, notifications

This weather app has an interesting notification type:

1. It's *always* expanded. Always.
2. There's no decoration/borders
3. It doesn't have rounded edges

Despite a lot of trying I failed to find out how to create such a notification. Does anybody know how it's called or could link to the relevant documentation or sample?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 SO posts that may help you:

[Is possible set Expanded Notification as default in Big Text Notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331682/is-possible-set-expanded-notification-as-default-in-big-text-notifications)

[Custom notification layout gives unnecessary margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028419/custom-notification-layout-gives-unnecessary-margin)

To set a notification as expanded in defualt you can do this

```
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))
```

to the notification

and for the next 2 queries you can implement a custom notification and then remove all the  styles and add your own

Comment: Not sure what you mean. 2 queries? Do mean making the notification visible and then replacing it with another one of a different style?

Comment: Regarding the links: I'm already using PRIORITY_MAX. But here has to be something else. No matter in which order I trigger the notifications, that weather app is *always* above my notification. And thus *always* expanded.